# Prove $S \doteq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) > 0$ assuming $0 \leq p_n < 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, infinite-product, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Prove $S \doteq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) > 0$ assuming $0 \leq p_n < 1$.

[Hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433541/borel-cantelli-related-exercise-show-that-s-1-to-prod-n-1-infty-1-p): Show that $S < 1 \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \geq 1 - S$.

---

Assuming the hint is true:

If $S \geq 1$ but $S < \infty$, then $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} p_n < 1$.

Define $T \doteq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q_m = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} p_n < 1$ where $q_1 = p_k, q_2 = p_{k+1}, ...$

By hint, $T \doteq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q_m < 1 \to \prod_{m=1}^{\infty} (1-q_m) > 0 \to \prod_{n=k}^{\infty} (1 - p_n) > 0 \to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - p_n) > 0$ (a reason why $p_n < 1$, I guess)

QED

Is that right?

Comment: Please refrain from double posting.

Comment: @LandonCarter I asked one question about the hint and another about the problem. Is that forbidden or discouraged?

Comment: Yes, actually. This results in double posting. Please combine this question into the earlier question posted.

Comment: @LandonCarter I wasn't aware of any such rule. May you pls provide a link? What is 'double posting' exactly? I am asking about the proofs of two propositions, one of which happens to imply the other. What exactly is wrong with that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1433541/15941 ?

Comment: @DilipSarwate That question asks about the hint. This one is about the main proposition

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry. Edited [title](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433541/borel-cantelli-related-exercise-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-p-n-1-implies).

Comment: @LandonCarter Sorry again for confusion. Edited title in other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $p_n \in [0,1)$ and
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty$.
>
> Prove $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n) > 0$.

---

There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433567/prove-s-doteq-sum-n-1-infty-p-n-infty-to-prod-n-1-infty-1-p-n), but I would like to try a different approach using continuity of measure, monotone convergence theorem and definition of supremum.

---

What I tried (I'm not sure if my lim, inf and sup statements are right):

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $X_n$ be iid Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p_n$ and in $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Then,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n<\infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n = 1) <\infty$$

By Borel-Cantelli Lemma 1 we have, $$P(\limsup(X_n = 1))=0$$

which is equivalent to $$P(\liminf(X_n = 0)) = 1$$

$$ \ $$

$$\to 1 =P(\bigcup_{N \ge 1} \bigcap_{n \ge N} (X_n=0))$$

By continuity of measure $\color{red}{\text{(I think?)}}$

$$= \lim_{N \to \infty}P(\bigcap_{n \ge N} (X_n=0))$$

By monotone convergence theorem $\color{red}{\text{(I think?)}}$

$$= \sup_{N \ge 1}P(\bigcap_{n \ge N} (X_n=0))$$

By independence,

$$ = \sup_{N \ge 1} \prod_{n=N}^{\infty} P(X_n=0)$$

$$= \sup_{N \ge 1} \prod_{n=N}^{\infty} (1-p_n)$$

$$\to \sup_{N \ge 1} \prod_{n=N}^{\infty} (1-p_n) = 1$$

$$\to \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists m \ge 1 \text{s.t.} \prod_{n=m}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \in (1-\epsilon, 1] \ \color{red}{\text{(I think?)}}$$

Since $p_n < 1 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\forall \epsilon \in (0,1), \exists m \ge 1 \text{s.t.} \prod_{n=m}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \in (1-\epsilon, 1] \ \color{red}{\text{(I think?)}}$$

Hence $\forall \epsilon \in (0,1), \exists m \ge 1 \text{s.t.}$

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-p_n)=\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}(1-p_n)\prod_{n=m}^{\infty}(1-p_n) > 0 \ \because$$

1. $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1}(1-p_n) > 0 \because p_n < 1 \ \forall n \ge 1$
2. $\prod_{n=m}^{\infty}(1-p_n) > 0 \because \prod_{n=m}^{\infty} (1-p_n) \in (1-\epsilon, 1]$ QED

Any mistakes? Again, I'm not sure if my lim, inf and sup statements are right.

Comment: Very good, BCLC! It is perfect! By the way, you may remove "I think" comments as the statements you have made are fine :) May I ask which course you are studying and how old you are?

Comment: Thanks @LandonCarter  ^-^ Mathematical finance. 21. Yourself? :P

Comment: Ah, I see why you are always looking at Borel-Cantelli, therefore. I am 19, studying Probability. :)

Comment: @LandonCarter 'MS Probability' ?

Comment: @LandonCarter Did your cool Bernoulli answer disappear?

Comment: @LandonCarter Do we need Bernoulli? I think we can just say $P(A_n)$ where $A_n$'s are independent?